# How To Show Only Hour in Kotlin? show data hh:mm:ss but I want To show hh:mm:ss to hh only

Tags: kotlin

How can I show only "hour" only in this? I don't want to show hour,minute,seconds, I want to show only "hour".

```
tvLate.text = String.format(response.data.overdue,Locale.ENGLISH,"'T'HH:mm.SSSZZZZZ") 
tvOverTime.text = response.data.overtime 
tvWork.text = response.data.total_work
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formulae to extract only **hour** from your timestamp:
`val hour = timestamp / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24`

Here instead of `timestamp` variable, you provide your timestamp / source of time in `Long` format.

Based on your below comments, I am adding few more steps:

Please follow the following steps:
a. Make sure that your `response.data.overdue` is a `Long`.
Because the above formuale will work only with `Long`.
b. Secondly do not mix the above formulae with `String.format()`.
c. Instead use `toString()`.

**For Example:**

```
val hour = response.data.overdue / (1000 * 60 * 60) % 24 // Here I am assuming that the response.data.overdue is a Long
val finalData = hour.toString()
And this finalData will have hours in String format.
```

Comment: ok sir thank u very much but parameter in backend as a string in overdue not long.